# Mail sending error from the IIS and Shared Server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Im doing a project where i have to send a link to my user/clients. The mail will be sent to them once they register their account. Now there will be a link in their mail when clicked on that link the users will be redirected once again to my website and they will be shown a pdf.

When i did this from my system and localserver it worked fine.

But now my project has been put up in the development server from where its not possible for me to send mail.

I get the following errors

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: AspPDF.NET 2.0.0.14045 has generated error #46: [ Opening output file failed: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Myesign\UploadedFiles\Signed\Support2(1).pdf' is denied. ]

Im not clear that what might be the possible reason for this error. The same project worked when i used the localserver and from my pc also worked fine but from the production server the same project is not working.

Also the link that i get in my mail id is

"http://localhost/ScriptResource.axd?d=n3csX8loR-nh3aSKQ4FNi7Vth7ZBerv1fa-7sJrneEaqqdsyYs5M1zxZ6mXbdwJ0oPXtyofmMkG8z9SZaK8qgo6xYZPs72x4Icy0pXeiYtTxb_JCbdFLZmwvpEToNB0tY6mtEQ2&t=2939b118"

in the above link dont need the "http://localhost/"  is there anything i can do about. Im sure there might be some way but im not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the code you use to generate and send the link via email? It may be a relative linking issue. Also, make sure the NTAUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE account has permission to read files in the PDF folder on the server, as that is the account used when a file is accessed on the server through IIS.

Comment: Hey thanks Martin. I got it man. I provided the admin rights to the folder containing the Pdf files. So it works fine now. Thanks a lot man

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have the whole saturday just to get this particular stuff. Thank you once again.

Comment: Is there any way that i can remove the letters localhost/ from my link. I mean i cant send it as a link to my users/clients. Is there any way? To remove that and use www instead of localhost

Comment: You should be able to, how do you send it? If the link is just constructed from a string, you can use String.Replace("localhost", "www.[your_website_url].com").